# How to handle Mat dialog pop up in protractor?

Tags: protractor, mat-dialog

I'm getting this error everytime
`NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //input[@id='nameInput'])`

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch it with

> element(by.id('nameInput'))

or

> $("nameInput")

And you need to wait for it to catch it

> browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('nameInput')))